# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, inner-classes

The compiler says

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token"
```

and point to this line in .cpp:

```
Node * Tree::buildTree(Node *myNode, int h) {
```

I am guessing it might be something about `typedef` but not really sure. What could the problem be?

.h file:

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

class Tree {
    public:
    Tree();
    Tree(Tree const & other);
    ~Tree();
    Tree const & operator=(Tree const & other);

    private:
    class Node {
        public:
        Node() {
            data = 0;
        };
        Node(Node const & other) {
            _copy(other);
        };
        ~Node() {};
        Node const & operator=(Node const & other) {
            if (this != &other) 
                _copy(other);
            return *this;
        };

        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        int data;

        private:
        void _copy(Node const & other) {
            data = other.data;
            left = other.left;
            right = other.right;
        };
    };

    Node *root;

    Node * buildTree(Node *myNode, int h);
};
```

.cpp file:

```
...

Node * Tree::buildTree(Node *myNode, int h) {
    if (h == 0)
        return NULL;
    myNode = new Node();
    myNode->left = buildTree(myNode->left, h - 1);
    myNode->right = buildTree(myNode->right, h - 1);
    return myNode;
}

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Node` is declared inside of `Tree`, so you need

```
Tree::Node * Tree::buildTree(Node *myNode, int h)
```

Comment: I was hoping someone would quote the standard as to why [only the return `Node` type needs to be qualified](http://ideone.com/G28eZ7)...

Comment: @Dukeling It is something to do with everything after `Tree::buildTree` being in the `Tree::` scope. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: See [basic.scope.class]/1 "5) The potential scope of a declaration that extends to or past the end of a class definition also extends
to the regions defined by its member definitions, even if the members are defined lexically outside the class (this includes [...] any portion of the declarator part of such definitions which follows the _declarator-id_, including a _parameter-declaration-clause_ [...])." `Tree::buildTree` is the declarator-id, so after that you're in class scope, and member of the class are in scope, so can be found by unqualified name lookup.